# How do i publish a firebase login app on amazon app store?

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, amazon-appstore

so i have been trying to publish my app on the amazon app store.
but as i have made my app on the firebase system i use mobile authentication or google login to let users login to my app but as amazon is not able to login to my app using those features they're unable to login to my app and is continuously rejecting my app.
can anyone please tell me what is the correct way to let them login to my app.
or do i need to create a fake login system with a fake account just for them to login.

here is my app link http://texts.ga
[image]

i did contacted them and told them to login via any of the two methods and they did login via the google login but still they are asking for login credentials again.

thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: Did you find the issue that triggers this, recently I uploaded my app that's based on firebase and amazon has reviewed my app functionality and made the app live when users downloaded it into their android devices they can't make a login. But when I made login from a side-load app it works perfectly. So, for that reason I took down my app from amazon app store

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication, along with some other Firebase products, require Google Play services installed on the device in order to work correctly.  Amazon devices don't have Google Play services, so Firebase Authentication will not work on them.

Comment: i too thought the same at first but as i said in my question they did logged in to my app using the google login method as i saw them pop up in the users list with a weird id